# Converting SQL to Linq-To-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, b.c1, b.c2
FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
WHERE a.a1 = b.a1 AND a.b1 = b.b2;
```

I need help converting above to Linq-To-Sql syntax.
The problem line is
`WHERE a.a1 = b.a1 AND a.b1 = b.b2`

If it is only one condition, it is easy.

```
var myQry =
    from a in tab1
    join b in tab2 on a.a1 == b.a1
```

I need help completing myQry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on multiple columns like this:

```
var myQry = 
    from a in tab1 
    join b in tab2 on new { a.a1, a.b1 } equals new { b.a1, b.b2 }
    select new { a.c1, a.c2, b.c1, b.c2 }
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var myQuery = tab1.Join(tab2, 
                        a => new { a.a1, a.b1 }, 
                        b => new { b.a1, b.b2 },
                        (a, b) => new { a.c1, a.c2, b.c1, b.c2 });
```